# Why PHP script restart itselt without showing an element on a page?

Tags: php

My problem is that if use the following code, after sumbitting the form, this is not showing the error message I want. I guess it simply restart the .php script itself, overriding the message I want to show.

```
<?php

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML>';
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css">';
echo '</head>';
echo '<body>';

function webform_show($erromessage)
{
echo '<div class="form1">';
echo '  <form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post" name="auth_form">';
echo '    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">';
echo '    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">';
echo '    <p id="error">'.$errormessage.'</p>';
echo '    <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">';
echo "  </form>";
echo '</div>';
}
webform_show("");

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {

    webform_show("Empty username or password");
    }
}

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

I would like to show the error message, but I want to keep the webform alive to be able to check the username and password again.

Could you help me what is the problem ?

Comment: It's so hard to read this when there is not highlighting.. Why would you open php tag where html is almost everything?

Comment: Move `webform_show("");` to `else`-branch of `_POST['login']`

Comment: Try adding else conditions to your 2 if statements, and echo some text in those elses (that way you know if either are not being met). I would imagine that the two POST username/password when empty, are not actually empty, but equal to "" (empty string).

Comment: Also, you are **not using** `$erromessage`. There is not `echo` for it there. **Edit:** to make it clear, there is a typo, `$errormessage` should be `$erromessage`. Notice the `R`.

Comment: @FirstOne read it again, he echos it inside the webform_show function.

Comment: @Matthew, FirstOne is correct, there is a typo in you argument

Comment: Fair enough, and good spot!

Comment: dmaij, Matthew Lymer,  FirstOne: fixed the typo, thank you!

Comment: Matthew Lymer: I will try add else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not "restarting" your script. You're simply calling `webform_show()` TWICE, after the form's been submitted.

You basically have:

```
webform_show(); // executes EVERY time script is called
if (... post was performed ...) {
   webform_show(); // executes every time a POST was performed
}
```

So... first hit on the page is a GET, you show the form once. Then the form gets submitted via POST, and you show the form twice.

And note that you have typos:

```
function webform_show($erromessage)
                           ^---
echo '    <p id="error">'.$errormessage.'</p>';
                               ^--- spot the difference
```

Comment: Marc B: thanks for pointing out the typo. 

I couldn't find easier way to show the error message, but keep the webform alive.

How can make sure webform_show() (without parameters)  called only when the page is opened first time?

Comment: `$error = ''; if (post) { process form, set $error if necessary}; show_webform($error);` basically